# Android R: query image items created only by the local Camera app

Tags: android, camera

On Android in the app we query all media items on the device and filter theirs to obtain items captured only by the local Camera app.

We use this query for create a cursor object:

```
 String where = MessageFormat.format("LOWER({0}) LIKE ''%/dcim/%'' AND NOT (LOWER({0}) LIKE ''%.thumbnails%''", 
                                     MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
 Cursor cursor = MediaStore.Images.Media.query(this,
                                               uri, 
                                               null, 
                                               where, 
                                               MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN);
```

Actually this worked well on Android SDK 29 and bellow, but now while test on SDK 30 simulator I found that the Camera app saves the captured photos not in "DCIM" folder but in "Pictures" folder, therefore the code above could not obtain the correct items.

I'm not sure if this intended behavior or simulator issue because I tried to test on one Samsung device with Android 11 and their Camera app saves to "DCIM/Camera" still.

Do you know the better way to check if media item has been created by local Camera app?

**Update 1**
Camera app has "com.android.camera2" package. And I can found the source code here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Camera2/
They changed the location of photos from "DCIM/Camera" to "Pictures" during "Update Storage method to be compatible with API 29" changes. Actually this was required because now the apps could not use direct File API and they migrated to MediaStore API. But don't know why they changed the folder. May be I can create some ticket for this.

Comment: Add an extra query for the Pictures folder.

Comment: Even if there are files in DCIM/Camera you cannot just say that they are from the default camera app. For that you would have to inspect exif information for instance.

Comment: Further i cannot remember that a 30 emulator would not save in DCIM/Camera. Further you talk both about R and 30 but R is not 30. Its sdk int is 29. Please adapt your post concerning this.

Comment: @blackapps This is not a problem to add "Pictures" to the query, but this a folder which should contain all pictures available to the user (as per the documentation) and I think in many cases it can contain also images not captured by the Camera app. Instead "DCIM" is traditional location for camera photos.
Inspect exif requires access to each file, this will decrease the performance dramatically in comparison to the database query. So I can use such solution only as the last resort.

Comment: @blackapps About the emulator - I simple try to create new one using the last version (revision 9) from the Google and on the both Linux/Mac the emulator still save the captured image to Pictures. May be you use use emulator not from Android Studio, something like Genymotion. Also Build.VERSION_CODES.R = 30 ....

Comment: One can create emulators for Q, API 30 and R. WIth all these emiulators the defauld Camera app stores in DCIM/Camera. Take an API 30 emulator as the R emulator behave like sdk int 29 Android 10.

Comment: Excuse me. Now i updated to revision 9 and the API 30 emulator starts clean and the default Camera app saves to Pictures instead of DCIM/Camera. We all wonder why this should be...